# perl subroutine returning array and str but they are getting merged

Tags: perl, subroutine

```
sub process_feed {
    my ($line) = @_; 

    my @lines;
    my $last_received = ""; 

    while (1) {
        if ($line =~/^{(.*?)}(.*)/) {
            push @lines, $1; 
            $line = $2; 
        } else {
            $last_received = $line;
            last;
        }   
    }   

    print "sending back @lines, $last_received\n";

    return (@lines, $last_received);
}

my (@lines, $leftover) = process_feed("{hi1}{hi2}{hi3");
print "got lines: @lines\n";
print "got last_recevied, $leftover\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
sending back hi1 hi2, {hi3
got lines: hi1 hi2 {hi3
got last_recevied,
```

EXPECTED:

```
sending back hi1 hi2, {hi3
got lines: hi1 hi2 
got last_recevied, {hi3
```

why did `$last_recevied` get merged to `@lines`?
how do i split them in the outer func?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function returns a flat list. If  an array is first in the list of variables being assigned to, the whole list goes into that array. So in

```
my (@lines, $leftover) = process_feed("{hi1}{hi2}{hi3");
```

the `@lines` gets everything that the sub returned.

Solutions

- Return a reference to an array along with a scalar, so assign to two scalars

  ```
  sub process_feed { 
       # ...
       return \@lines, $last_received;
   }
   my ($rlines, $leftover) = process_feed("{hi1}{hi2}{hi3");
   print "got lines: @$rlines\n";
  ```

  I would recommend this approach, in general.
- Since `$last_received` is always returned, swap the order in the return and assignment

  ```
  sub process_feed { 
      # ...
      return $last_received, @lines;
  }
  my ($leftover, @lines) = process_feed("{hi1}{hi2}{hi3");
  ```

Since the assignment is to a scalar first only one value from the return is assigned to it and then others go into next variables. Here it is the array `@lines`, which takes all remaining return.