# Odd number of elements in hash assignment with default

Tags: perl

Greeting Dear Community.

I'm trying to make a `sub` in perl that takes a hash and a debug flag which defaults to zero. However I keep getting this error `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`. If I don't use the debug flag, it seems to work.

Thanks for all the help.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use POSIX qw(strftime);


#
#file2hash : read the file in k<file_name> e.g.=kconfig &  kmem  into hash table
#

sub file2hash {
    my ($file) = @_;

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

my %HoH;
my $key;
my $value;
my $who;
my $rec;
my $field;

#while ( my $line = <$data>) {
while ( <$data>) {
    #print $line;
    next unless (s/^(.*?):\s*//); # / turn off editor coloring
    $who = $1;
    #print $who;
    $rec = {};
    $HoH{$who} = $rec;
    for $field ( split ) {
        ($key, $value) = split /=/, $field;
        $rec->{$key} = $value;
    }
}

    return %HoH;

}
#
#end file2hash
#


#
#print out hash table in k<file_name> format
#
sub hash2print{
    (my %HoH,my $debug) = @_;
    #my ($debug)=@_||0;
    #my %HoH = shift;
    #my $debug = shift || 0;

    my $family;
    my $role;

    for $family ( keys %HoH ) {
        #print "$family\n";
        for $role ( keys %{ $HoH{$family} } ) {
             if ($debug){
                print "family:$family\n";
                print "role: $role\n";
             }
             print "$role=$HoH{$family}{$role}";

        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
#
#end hash2print
#

sub dispatch{

        my $inc= shift;
        my $config_f = shift || "kconfig";
        my $memory_f = shift || "kmem";

        my %h2=&file2hash($config_f);
        my %m2=file2hash($memory_f);

        my $today=&getDate();

        print "$today\n";
        print "$inc\n";
        my $inc_cnt = $m2{$today}{$inc} || -999999999;
        print "$inc_cnt\n";

        #my %config = shift;
        #my %mem = shift;
        #my $event = shift;
        #print $m2{$inc}{$today};
}

sub getDate{
my $date = strftime "%m/%d/%Y", localtime;  # "
#print $date;
return $date;
}

my %h2=&file2hash("kconfig");
my %m2=&file2hash("kmem");
&hash2print(%h2,1);
&hash2print(%m2,1);
#print &getDate();
#my $xcnt= &dispatch("event_c3_z2");
#&dispatch("event_c3_z2");
#print $xcnt;
```

Test file1:

```
event_a1_x1: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=6
event_a1_x2: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=5 
event_b2_y1: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=4 
event_b2_y2: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=3 
event_c3_z1: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=2 
event_c3_z2: email1=ackee0000@gmail.com email2=kym018@gmail.com email1_cnt=1
```

test file2:

```
201609230012: event_a1_x1=6
201609230744: event_a1_x2=5
201609230844: event_b2_y1=4
201609230342: event_b2_y2=3
201609230245: event_c3_z1=2
201609230100: event_c3_z2=1
```

Comment: I edited your post to turn off the wrong (red) coloring. It happens often after a regex or such where the editor gets confused by slashes or such and then colors everything red after that point. Most of the time adding a comment `# /` solves it, but sometimes you need to try different characters in the comment.  If you don't like this please "roll back" my edit -- go to "edited (time)" link above my username and you'll see revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass your hashes by value to your subroutine and this creates the problem. Try to pass your hash `%h2` by reference instead (notice the `\` before the `%`):

```
&hash2print(\%h2, 1);
```

Then in your sub `hash2print`, you can get the hash back in the following way:

```
sub hash2print {
    (my $hashref, my $debug) = @_;
    my %HoH = %$hashref; # dereference $hashref to get back the hash
    ...
```

You can read more about references [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) if you don't understand the concepts behind them.

Answer (score 4):

Arguments are passed to a function as one flat list. On the other hand, a hash can be assigned a list, `%h = qw(a b)`, where consecutive elements form key-value pairs, `$h{a}` is `'b'`. So when a hash is the first variable that receives arguments in a function it scoops up all of them.  Here is a [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502670/perl-subroutine-returning-array-and-str-but-they-are-getting-merged/39502917#39502917) on how a function *returns*, where the exact same story applies.

So everything is assigned to the hash, the remaining scalar as well.  Thus the hash gets one more element than intended and ends up with an odd number of elements.

A solution -- in this case, only to pass hash by reference, as in the answer by [Inferno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379631/inferno)

```
sub hash2print{
    my ($rHoH, $debug) = @_;
    my %HoH = %$rHoH;
    # ...
}
hash2print(\%h2, 1);
```

It is in principle a good idea to pass lists by reference, unless they are very short.

In general you can pass the scalar first then the hash

```
sub hash2print{
    my ($value, %HoH) = @_;
    # ...
}
hash2print(1, %h2);
```

But in your case this doesn't go since the `$debug` is optional, and if we leave it out when calling the function the first key of the hash would wind up in `$value`.

A few other comments

- Don't use globals unless there is a non-negotiable reason for that. Declare in small scope.
- You don't have to do `$rec = {};`, can just declare it `my $rec;`.
- In general, don't put `&` in front of a function call but use just `file2hash(...)`;

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much for the fix.