# Perl get parameter datatype

Tags: perl

Am trying to make a subroutine that replaces data depending on datatype: the problem is i can't get the datatype of the parameter, i used this:

```
 sub replace {
      my ($search, $replacement, $subject) = @_;

      if (ref($search) eq "HASH") {
          print "r is a reference to a HASH.\n";
      }
      elsif (ref($search) eq "SCALAR") {
          print "r is a reference to a SCALAR.\n";
      }
      elsif (ref($search) eq "ARRAY") {
          print "r is a reference to a ARRAY.\n";
      }
  }

my $str = "Foo";
my @arr = ("Foo");

replace($str);
replace(@arr);
```

But none works. am really new to perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ref()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) takes a *reference* to something, not the something itself. Here:

```
replace($str);
replace(@arr);
```

...you are sending in the something directly. Send in a reference to the something instead, by putting a `\` in front of it (which says, "take a reference to this something"):

```
replace(\$str);
replace(\@arr);
```

Output:

```
r is a reference to a SCALAR.
r is a reference to a ARRAY.
```

Note also that in your `replace()` function, in this line:

```
my ($search, $replacement, $subject) = @_;
```

You are effectively asking for a scalar value as the thing to search, so passing in a list (array, hash etc) will clobber `$replacement` and `$subject` if the passed in list has more than one element, so you may want to do something like this to ensure you're getting the proper params, and nothing is clobbered unexpectedly:

```
sub replace {
    my ($search, $replacement, $subject) = @_;
    die "first arg must be a ref\n" if ! ref $search;
```

Of course, you can do further argument checking, but this'll ensure that the first parameter can only be a reference to something. Instead of `die()`, you can also just `return` so the program doesn't crash, or `print` or `warn` and then `return`.

Comment: is there any other way apart from adding \ to it? like can i do it inside the subroutine?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu no, because function parameters appear to perl as one big list, so you can not differentiate a list of scalars, an array or a hash after the function has already accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not stated what you want to do with it, but here's what is wrong with what you show.

The [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function shows the datatype of the *reference* subtmitted to it, or it returns an empty string if its argument isn't a reference at all.

So to get the expected behavior you should do

```
replace(\$str);
replace(\@arr);
```

Also, you need to add the test to your function

```
else (not ref $search)
```

for when a submitted string is not a reference.

---

For completeness, I should also point out an issue, explained in the answer by [stevieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334695/stevieb).  When you pass an array to a function, it receives it as a flat list of arguments. With your function you clearly do not want `replace(@arr)`.  They are assigned to your list of scalar variables in order, one element to each. (As soon as there is an array variable it all goes into it.) See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670453/odd-number-of-elements-in-hash-assignment-with-default/39670787#39670787).