# Perl find out if X is an element in an array

Tags: perl, grep

I don't know why small things are too not working for me in Perl. I am sorry for that.

I have been trying it around 2 hrs but i couldn't get the results.

```
my $technologies = 'json.jquery..,php.linux.';
my @techarray = split(',',$technologies);

#my @techarray = [
#          'json.jquery..',
#          'php.linux.'
#        ];

my $search_id = 'json.jquery..';

check_val(@techarray, $search_id);
```

And i am doing a "if" to search the above item in array. but it is not working for me.

```
 sub check_val{
        my @techarray = shift;
        my $search_id = shift;
          if (grep {$_ eq $search_id} @techarray) {
                print "It is there \n";
            }else{
                print "It is not there \n";
            }
     }
```

Output: It always going to else condition and returns "It is not there!" :(

Any idea. Am i done with any stupid mistakes?

Comment: Change your array assignment to:  `my @techarray = ('json.jquery..', 'php.linux.');`

Comment: @techarray is an output from "split" method.

Comment: If your problem can't be reproduced as written in the question, then you need to create a proper [mcve].

Comment: Can you explain what that means, _`@techarray` is an output from "split" method_ ?

Comment: @zdim.  I just updated my question for the Split method.

Comment: What you have now, after the edit, _should_ work just as it stands.  The `split` returns a list and you feed it into the array `@techarray`.  All good. What is commented out now, `@techarray = [ ... ]` was wrong.

Comment: Hey @zdim, I am sorry. I again updated my question.

Comment: Inside `check_val`, `@techarray` does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an *anonymous array* `[ ... ]` there, which as a scalar (reference) is then assigned to `@techarray`, as its only element. It is like `@arr = 'a';`. An array is defined by `( ... )`.

A remedy is to either define an array, `my @techarray = ( ... )`, or to properly define an arrayref and then dereference when you search

```
my $rtecharray = [ .... ];
if (grep {$_ eq $search_id} @$rtecharray) {
    # ....
}
```

For all kinds of list manipulations have a look at [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) and [List::MoreUtils](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html).

---

*Updated to changes in the question, as the sub was added*

This has something else, which is more instructive.

As you pass an array to a function it is passed as a flat list of its elements. Then in the function the first `shift` picks up the first element, 
and then the second `shift` picks up the second one.

Then the search is over the array with only `'json.jquery..'` element, for `'php.linux.'` string.

Instead, you can pass a reference,

```
check_val(\@techarray, $search_id);
```

and use it as such in the function.

---

**Note** that if you pass the array and get arguments in the function as

```
my (@array, $search_id) = @_;  # WRONG
```

you are in fact *getting all of `@_` into `@array`*.

See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670453/odd-number-of-elements-in-hash-assignment-with-default/39670787#39670787) (passing to function) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502670/perl-subroutine-returning-array-and-str-but-they-are-getting-merged/39502917#39502917) (returning from function).

In general I'd recommend passing lists by reference.

Comment: Wow... You are right. I just defined an arrayref and then dereferenced and that starts working. :)

Comment: In your second example, `@array` would contain everything and `$search_id` would be `undef`.